# Machine-Readable Pronunciation/Stress Dictionary for Ukrainian?

Tags: наголос, фонетика, software, словники, syllables

I am aware (thanks largely to [this meta post](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8/259)) that there are several dictionaries online that provide stress, such as:

- [ULIF](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/)
- [slovnyk.ua](https://www.slovnyk.ua/)

However, I'd prefer something:

- Machine readable
- Usable in commercial software
- Usable offline (such as a large text file like the [CMU dictionary](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/cmusphinx/code/trunk/cmudict/cmudict-0.7b) is for English)

(Answers that don't meet all these criteria are still welcome as they may be useful to others)

(There may be an answer in [the aforementioned meta post](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8/259), as I was only able to read the English answer, since my Ukrainian is still at a very basic level.

Answer (score 3):

Here is [a question about open-data Ukrainian dictionaries](/q/1334/) (though, sadly for you the question and its answers are in Ukrainian).

In short, the only stuff I know (both are covered in answers to that questions) is:

- [Ukrainian Wiktionary](//uk.wiktionary.org). MediaWiki formatting isn't easily parsable, but as you need only stress/pronunciation, it should be enough for you to extract a limited set of patterns from each page (e.g. `|склади=до-мі́в-ка` and `|склади={{склади|слов|ни́к}}`) (the largest problem is probably that Ukrainian Wiktionary may rarely contain entries about words in other languages, so you will also need to parse top-level headings to extract `|склади=` only from sections about Ukrainian words); Wiktionary allows to download all pages in [a single dump](//dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index.html). The main problem is that as for now it contains not so much words (you can also try to parse Russian and English Wiktionaries — sometimes that contain entries about Ukrainian words that Ukrainian Wiktionary misses — but that probably won't help a lot).
- [mhpdict](//github.com/LinguisticAndInformationSystems/mphdict/wiki). The problem with that source is that, despite mhpdict provides all of its databases under open licence ([ODbL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_License) 1.0), the legibility of mhpdict databases themselves is under question: it claimed to be based on the 7-volume [Etymological dictionary of the Ukrainian language](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8), while the copyright holders of the 7-volume Etymological dictionary were quite indignant about that and sued (or, at least, were going to sue some time ago) the mhpdict authors.

<sub>In general, sadly, Ukraine as for now has quite low level of culture in the field of intellectual property. Most of Ukrainians simply don't understand what's it all about: neither why one can't just take info from anyone else's site, nor why development of open data / free information is beneficial. If your goal is purely self-educational then you could probably just grab data from any of the websites providing stressed Ukrainian words (many of widely-available Ukrainian dictionary sites aren't license-clean themselves; no one would probably sue you unless you openly advertise that fact) — but if you're going to embed it into commercial software and/or need reliable data sources and/or want to do it 100%-right, then just grabbing a random Ukrainian dictionary site is probably not your way.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

This Python application exists now:

https://github.com/lang-uk/ukrainian-word-stress

It took me a while, as a complete Python novice, but I eventually got it working.

Comment: This is great! I wish I had something like this back in 2018. I'm curious, where did you get the underlying data file? I didn't see anything on that in the docs.